# Installing Magit from its Git repository

Tags: magit

I am a newbie. How do I install Magit from its git repository? Where do you copy the repositories of Emacs packages? And how to get the correct path in Aquamacs?

Comment: Try Googling:  **how do I install magit**  Also, do yourself a favor and don't use Aquamacs unless the OSX native spellchecker is the most important thing in the world to you.  Use the vanilla build of Emacs for OSX instead:  http://emacsformacosx.com/  People will recommend macports or homebrew, but that won't give you a self-contained application package with everything you need.  If you like your stuff in several different locations on your hard drive, then by all means go with homebrew or macports.

Answer (score 2):

Of course that is [covered by the manual](http://magit.vc/manual/magit/Installing-from-the-Git-repository.html).

Personally I install all my packages as git submodules. To do that I run.

```
git submodule add --name magit git@github.com:magit/magit.git lib/magit
```